# XMPPFramework - How to receive the presence info of a roster along with roster list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

Need help in getting the information on a presence information of a buddy.

I am calling "fetchRoster" function, however am getting the list for roster but not the presence information.

Also i tried calling  presence information of a explicitly.But didRecievePresence delegate is not getting called in my iOS app.

Regards,
Cbhat

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information. We can't guess what your method look like and how your code work. Please provide the code that you think is relevant.

Comment: Emilie, I am developing a chat application. For that am using XMPPFramework [https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework] .I am able to get my buddy list when i call [XMPPRoster fetchRoster]. However now i want retrieve their (Presence info ->)Profile pic, status info and nick name information. These info are not coming along with fetch roster call. So i wanted to know how can i get presence info of a buddy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From Robbiehanson's XMPPFramework - RootViewController class:](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/RootViewController.m)

1. Fetch your roster

   ```
   - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
   {
       if (fetchedResultsController == nil)
       {
           NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

           NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];

           NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
           NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

           NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

           NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
           [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
           [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
           [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

           fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                          managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                     cacheName:nil];
           [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];


           NSError *error = nil;
           if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
           {
               DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
           }
       }

       return fetchedResultsController;
   }
   ```
2. Reload your table whenever a change in a user's presence is recorded in the server

   ```
   - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   {
       [[self tableView] reloadData];
   }
   ```
3. Display avatars (profile pictures)

   ```
   - (void)configurePhotoForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell user:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)user
   {
       // Our xmppRosterStorage will cache photos as they arrive from the xmppvCardAvatarModule.
       // We only need to ask the avatar module for a photo, if the roster doesn't have it.

       if (user.photo != nil)
       {
           cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
       } 
       else
       {
           NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

           if (photoData != nil)
               cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
           else
               cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
       }
   }
   ```
4. Break down the table into two sections - Available/Offline

   ```
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
   {
       NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

       if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
       {
           id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];

           int section = [sectionInfo.name intValue];
           switch (section)
           {
               case 0  : return @"Available";
               case 1  : return @"Away";
               default : return @"Offline";
           }
       }

       return @"";
   }
   ```
5. Display your entire roster with user's display name

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil)
       {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       }

       XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       cell.textLabel.text = user.displayName;
       [self configurePhotoForCell:cell user:user];

       return cell;
   }
   ```

This is included in the XMPPFramework which you've downloaded. Experiment with it. These 5 points I stated might be what you need.

Comment: It's returning resource of user nil. Have you any solution for it?